# Looping Through Min Date for a Member -Performance Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to loop each time for a date for every member and define a status for a member. This query is working perfectly fine but this is taking lot of time. I cannot think of alternate way to get this result set.

Logic,

```
For every member, look for minimum date, then add 30 to it, if any date falls under  30, then status is initial_1. If it is greater than 30 and less than 30+15, then Reauth_1_1, if date greater than 30+16 , then it is intial_2.

MemberID    DOS         Status
HHH00031200 7/17/2014   Initial_1
HHH00031200 7/29/2014   Initial_1
HHH00031200 8/21/2014   Re-Auth_1_1
HHH00031200 8/27/2014   Re-Auth_1_1
HHH50000000 5/23/2016   Initial_1
HHH50000000 7/19/2016   Initial_2
HHH50000000 9/13/2016   Initial_3
HHH88844900 9/19/2015   Initial_1
HHH88844900 10/22/2015  Re-Auth_1_1
HHH88844900 11/24/2015  Re-Auth_1_2
HHH88844900 12/10/2015  Re-Auth_1_2
HHH22227700 1/16/2014   Initial_1
HHH22227700 2/21/2014   Re-Auth_1_1
HHH22227700 2/25/2014   Re-Auth_1_1
HHH22227700 3/5/2014    Re-Auth_1_1
HHH22227700 1/1/2015    Initial_2
HHH22227700 1/15/2015   Initial_2
HHH22227700 1/20/2015   Initial_2
HHH22227700 2/10/2015   Re-Auth_2_1
HHH22227700 2/12/2015   Re-Auth_2_1
HHH22227700 2/17/2015   Re-Auth_2_1
HHH22227700 2/19/2015   Re-Auth_2_1
HHH22227700 2/25/2015   Re-Auth_2_1
HHH22227700 2/26/2015   Re-Auth_2_1
```

Query:

```
--drop table #Temp_SO_Check
Select
    *
Into #Temp_SO_Check
From #auth;

CREATE  INDEX IDX_C_Users_UserID ON #Temp_SO_Check(MemberID,DOS,LoopLogic);

While Exists
(
    Select Top 1
        MemberID
    From    #Temp_SO_Check
    Where   LoopLogic Is Null
)
Begin
    Select Top 1
        @ID = MemberID
        , @StartDate = DOS
    From    #Temp_SO_Check
    Where   LoopLogic Is Null
    Order By
        MemberID
        , DOS;

    If @PrevID <> @ID
    Begin
        set @Flag=1;
        Set @LoopLogic ='Initial_'+Cast(@Flag as nvarchar(50)) ;
        Set @PrevID = @ID;
        set @ReauthFlag=0;
    end 
    else 
    Begin
        if((@LookupDate is not null) and (datediff(day,@LookupDate,@StartDate))<14)
        Begin       
            Set @LoopLogic ='Re-Auth_'+Cast(@Flag as nvarchar(50)) ;
        End
        Else if ((@LookupDate is not null) and (datediff(day,@LookupDate,@StartDate))>14)
        Begin
            set @Flag=@Flag+1;
            set @ReauthFlag=0;
            Set @LoopLogic ='Initial_'+Cast(@Flag as nvarchar(50));
        End
    End

    Set @LookupDate = DateAdd(Day, 30, @StartDate);
    if( (@LoopLogic like '%Re-Auth_%') and (@LookupDate<>@LookupDate1))
    Begin
        Set @ReauthFlag=@ReauthFlag+1;
        Set @LoopLogic ='Re-Auth_'+Cast(@Flag as nvarchar(50))+'_'+Cast(@ReauthFlag as nvarchar(50)) ;
    End

    set @LookupDate1=@LookupDate;

    Update
        #Temp_SO_Check
    Set
        LoopLogic = @LoopLogic
    Where
        MemberID = @ID
        And DOS Between @StartDate
                    And     @LookupDate;

End;
```

**#auth table has my data and then the looping stats. i have 766000 records and it is taking more than 1 hour 30 minutes and still running.**

Can anybody please help me fine tune this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a very interesting question. Originally I had hoped to find a solution using window functions like [`lag()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), but because there's no good way to know how many records separate any given record from the preceding record that represents the start of the same interval, I ended up having to use recursion. I'm not sure how this will perform for you over a very large data set, and if you have a large number of entries per `MemberID` then you may have to add a [`MAXRECURSION` query hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-2017), but I hope it will at least perform better than an iterative solution. The comments within the query explain what's going on.

```
-- Sample data from the question.
declare @SampleData table (MemberID varchar(32), DOS date);
insert @SampleData values
    ('HHH00031200', '20140717'),
    ('HHH00031200', '20140729'),
    ('HHH00031200', '20140821'),
    ('HHH00031200', '20140827'),
    ('HHH50000000', '20160523'),
    ('HHH50000000', '20160719'),
    ('HHH50000000', '20160913'),
    ('HHH88844900', '20150919'),
    ('HHH88844900', '20151022'),
    ('HHH88844900', '20151124'),
    ('HHH88844900', '20151210'),
    ('HHH22227700', '20140116'),
    ('HHH22227700', '20140221'),
    ('HHH22227700', '20140225'),
    ('HHH22227700', '20140305'),
    ('HHH22227700', '20150101'),
    ('HHH22227700', '20150115'),
    ('HHH22227700', '20150120'),
    ('HHH22227700', '20150210'),
    ('HHH22227700', '20150212'),
    ('HHH22227700', '20150217'),
    ('HHH22227700', '20150219'),
    ('HHH22227700', '20150225'),
    ('HHH22227700', '20150226');

-- First, assign every record from our data set a sequence number, where the
-- record having the earliest DOS for any MemberID has [Sequence] = 1 and the
-- value of [Sequence] increases by 1 for each subsequent DOS.
with OrderedDataCTE as
(
    select
        S.MemberID,
        S.DOS,
        [Sequence] = row_number() over (partition by S.MemberID order by S.DOS)
    from
        @SampleData S
),

-- Here's the recursive CTE, where the real work is done. Its purpose is to
-- split the initial data set into intervals. I use the term "interval" to mean
-- a set of records that have the same MemberID and the same status.
IntervalCTE as
(
    -- Base case: Any record with [Sequence] = 1 is the first record for its
    -- MemberID, so we know this represents the beginning of a new interval
    -- that will ultimately have the status Initial_1.
    select
        O.MemberID,
        O.DOS,
        O.[Sequence],

        -- IntervalStartDate will be the DOS of the record that defines the
        -- start of the current interval. Since every record in the base case
        -- marks a new interval, this is always the DOS.
        IntervalStartDate = O.DOS,

        -- Given that our final record statuses will either be of the form
        -- Initial_X or Re-Auth_X_Y, AuthNumber will represent the value X. At
        -- the start of the first interval for a new MemberID, the value is
        -- always 1, because every member's first status is Initial_1.
        AuthNumber = 1,

        -- ReAuthNumber will represent the value Y (see comments above), and
        -- will be set to 0 for statuses of the form Initial_X. At the start of
        -- the first interval for a new MemberID, the value is always 0.
        ReAuthNumber = 0
    from
        OrderedDataCTE O
    where
        O.[Sequence] = 1

    union all

    -- Recursive case: For each MemberID we find the record in the original
    -- data set having the next-highest [Sequence] number, and compare it to
    -- the record for that MemberID with the preceding [Sequence] number in
    -- order to figure out its status.
    select
        This.MemberID,
        This.DOS,
        This.[Sequence],

        -- If this record occurs within 30 days of the start of the interval
        -- that includes the preceding record, then this record is part of the
        -- same interval and thus has the same interval start date. Otherwise,
        -- this record marks the beginning of a new interval, which starts on
        -- this record's DOS.
        IntervalStartDate = case when datediff(day, Prev.IntervalStartDate, This.DOS) < 30 then Prev.IntervalStartDate else This.DOS end,

        -- If this record occurs within 45 days of the start of the interval
        -- that includes the preceding record, then its AuthNumber is the same
        -- as the preceding record. Otherwise it increments by 1.
        AuthNumber = case when datediff(day, Prev.IntervalStartDate, This.DOS) < 45 then Prev.AuthNumber else Prev.AuthNumber + 1 end,

        -- If this record occurs within 30 days of the start of the interval
        -- that includes the preceding record, then this record is part of the
        -- same interval and thus has the same ReAuthNumber.
        --
        -- If the above is not true but the record occurs within 45 days of the
        -- start of the interval that includes the preceding record, then the
        -- ReAuthNumber increments by 1.
        --
        -- If neither of the above is true, then we know that the AuthNumber
        -- will have increased (above), so the ReAuthNumber resets to 0.
        ReAuthNumber = 
            case
                when datediff(day, Prev.IntervalStartDate, This.DOS) < 30 then Prev.ReAuthNumber 
                when datediff(day, Prev.IntervalStartDate, This.DOS) < 45 then Prev.ReAuthNumber + 1
                else 0
            end
    from
        IntervalCTE Prev
        inner join OrderedDataCTE This on
            Prev.MemberID = This.MemberID and
            Prev.[Sequence] = This.[Sequence] - 1
)

-- At this point we can trivially construct each record's status from the
-- AuthNumbers and ReAuthNumbers assigned above.
select
    I.MemberID,
    I.DOS,
    [Status] =
        case
            when I.ReAuthNumber = 0 then 'Initial_' + convert(varchar, I.AuthNumber)
            else 'Re-Auth_' + convert(varchar, I.AuthNumber) + '_' + convert(varchar, I.ReAuthNumber)
        end
from
    IntervalCTE I
order by
    I.MemberID,
    I.[Sequence];
```

Results:

```
MemberID      DOS          Status
------------------------------------------------
HHH00031200   2014-07-17   Initial_1
HHH00031200   2014-07-29   Initial_1
HHH00031200   2014-08-21   Re-Auth_1_1
HHH00031200   2014-08-27   Re-Auth_1_1
HHH22227700   2014-01-16   Initial_1
HHH22227700   2014-02-21   Re-Auth_1_1
HHH22227700   2014-02-25   Re-Auth_1_1
HHH22227700   2014-03-05   Re-Auth_1_1
HHH22227700   2015-01-01   Initial_2
HHH22227700   2015-01-15   Initial_2
HHH22227700   2015-01-20   Initial_2
HHH22227700   2015-02-10   Re-Auth_2_1
HHH22227700   2015-02-12   Re-Auth_2_1
HHH22227700   2015-02-17   Re-Auth_2_1
HHH22227700   2015-02-19   Re-Auth_2_1
HHH22227700   2015-02-25   Re-Auth_2_1
HHH22227700   2015-02-26   Re-Auth_2_1
HHH50000000   2016-05-23   Initial_1
HHH50000000   2016-07-19   Initial_2
HHH50000000   2016-09-13   Initial_3
HHH88844900   2015-09-19   Initial_1
HHH88844900   2015-10-22   Re-Auth_1_1
HHH88844900   2015-11-24   Re-Auth_1_2
HHH88844900   2015-12-10   Re-Auth_1_2
```

Comment: thank you. i am trying to run this code but did hit the recursion limit. so I gave OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)  at the end of the Select (at the end of the code before ;).. this is running for 36 minutes now.  Am I doing something wrong? I know maxrecursion 0 is infinte loop.

Comment: @chits - The recursion should terminate eventually, so I don't think you're doing anything wrong. It just means this doesn't perform as well as I hoped it would. Out of curiosity, what is the largest number of records that occurs in your table for a single `MemberID`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop at all... and looping in SQL Server is a performance killser. Here's a simple solution

```
--determine the minimum date for the table, and add 30 days to it
declare @minDate date = (select dateadd(day,30,min(DOS)) DT from YourTable)


--based on your logic in the question, update the status column
update YouTable
set [Status] = case 
                when DOS < @minDate then 'initial_1'
                when DOS > @minDate and DOS < dateadd(day,15,@minDate) then 'Reauth_1_1'
                else 'intial_2'
               end
```

If the min date is per each employee, then I'd handle it in a CTE

```
;with cte as(
select
    MemberID    
    ,DOS         
    ,[Status]
    ,MinDOS = dateadd(day,30,min(DOS) over (partition by MemberID))
from YourTable)

update cte
set [Status] = case 
                when DOS < MinDOS then 'initial_1'
                when DOS > MinDOS and DOS < dateadd(day,15,MinDOS) then 'Reauth_1_1'
                else 'intial_2'
               end
```

Comment: Hi, this is not fixed to initial_1 or Initial_2, it should loop through all the records and it can be initial_3, Initial_4 etc depending on how many records we have. Similarlly with Reauth_1.

Comment: then you need to explain how that logic works... but it sounds god awful. Sop thinking in loops though. SQL is set based.

Comment: hi, Is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I did not know how to copy this in comment and thought of answering the question. 
Please correct me if there is a better way of posting the details.

Here is the Requirement:

```
1.For any member, look for minimum DOS, now add +30 to this date. 
2. As a first step we need to slice the data by 30 days window.
3.For example, minimum DOS for  memberid HHH00031200 is 7/17/2014. 
4. Add 30 days to it and it is 8/16/2014. 
5. Now for any date between 7/17/2014-8/16/2014 the status is Initial_1(This is the first window).
6.Now again add + 30 days to 8/16/2018. 
7.But in next window, if any date is within 15 days(i.e.8/16/2014+ 15 days) , it will be Reauth_1_1.if the date is > 15 days, then Initial_2 and this goes on till we loop all the records.
8.For example, Let us calculate the window for HHH88844900.
i. First Window-09/19/2015+30=10/19/2015
ii. Second Window-10/19/2015+30=11/21/2015
iii.third Window-11/21/2015+30=12/24/2015
9.First Loop Logic is always Initial_1.
10.Second Date is 10/22/2015 which is 3 days after the first window and that is why it is Re-Auth_1_1.
11.Third Date is 11/24/2015 which is 3 days after second window and that is why it is Re-Auth_1_2. similarlly last one. 
12.If the dates were > 15 days from the 30 days window, it would be Initial_2 ,for example MemeberId HHH50000000.
13.For memberId HHH22227700 , once we have the Initial_2, then the next dates would be Re-Auth_2_1 and so on..
```

Let me know if this made any sense. thanks for all your help.